# ngIf not working in grand child directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Before I had create grand child using directive, and everything is work normal until I using directive `*ngIf` in `grandchild` component, `*ngIf` is not working.

I had try to found the solution, but not found any thing to settle this problem.

here is my grand-child-directive directive

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'grand-child-directive ',
})
export class gc{
  @Input() name:string;
}
```

This is my child-component ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss'],    
})

export class childComponent implements AfterContentInit 

@ContentChildren(GrandChildDirective) gc:QueryList<GrandChildDirective> ;

  constructor(
  ) {    
  }
  person:any[] = [] 
  ngAfterContentInit() {
      this.gc.toArray().map(item=>{
           this.person.push(item)
      })         
  }
}
```

here is grandchild template

```html
<div *ngFor="let prsn of person">
    <a>prsn.name</a>  
</div>
```

and here is my template code to call `child` and `grandchild`

```html
<child-component>
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Ghandy'  *ngIf="showGhandy"></grand-child-directive >
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Ani'  *ngIf="showAni"></grand-child-directive >
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Budi' *ngIf="showBudi"></grand-child-directive >
</child-component>
```

and here is my ts

```js
export class testComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {             
    }
    showGhandy= true
    showAni= true
    showBudi:boolean = true
    ngOnInit(){
        if(someCondition){
             this.showGhandy = false
        }
        if(someCondition){
             this.showAni= false
        }
        if(someCondition){
             this.showBudi= false
        }   
    }
}
```

Person still visible even the condition is false

Am i missing something?

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with your code. Can you reproduce your problem?

Comment: @zmag : i also confused about my problem, as you say.. nothing wrong with my code.. by actually i got some issue in my code

Comment: Your `grand-child-directive` is directive, it there should be no template. This let me confused, can you provide a reproduction in https://stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Your grand child is a directive but you use it like a component. You should create your grand child as a component.